# Probability that internet users post photos online

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Online photos Suppose (as is roughly true) that 20% of all Internet users have posted photos online. A sample survey interviews an SRS of $1555$ Internet users.

(a) Describe the shape, center, and spread of the distribution of the proportion in the sample who have posted photos online.

(b) What is the probability that $300$ or fewer people in the sample have posted photos online? Use the distribution in (a) to help answer this question.

My answers:

A) shape - skewed right; center - $.30$; spread - $1$

B) $P(x<300)$ = ???
I know that p^ = $311$, but I'm apparently not calculating sigma right.

---

Book Answer:

Correct Answer

(a) has an approximately Normal distribution with center $μ$ = $p$ = $0.2$ and

(b) $P( ≤ 0.1929)$ = $P(Z ≤ −0.70)$ = $0.2420$.